# Is special PDF viewer required to see animations on beamer?

Tags: beamer, animations, animate, gif

I was trying to include a .gif file, and have the animation included in my presentation (using beamer).
I have splitted the .gif file into 21 .png files.
Next, used this code :

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{animate}
\begin{frame}
\animategraphics[autoplay,loop,height=3cm]{5}{file_}{1}{21} 
\end{frame}
```

But on my pdf (I have Adobe Reader X1 installed) I just find static image. So can anyone tell me please what is required in order to view the animation on the pdf file?
Thanks for your patience!

Comment: Adobe Reader has a number of settings. Perhaps you do not have the correct settings enabled? JavaScript?

Comment: Which operating system do you have?

Comment: @RobtAll, is there a way to change that? From Quick google search I understand there is something called Interactive Pdf which might support animations, but I'm not sure how to change what I have  currently , to that form :/

Comment: @samcarter I am using Windows 10, any idea how to be able to see animations on pdfs?

Comment: @ChanBan Have a look into the preferences of adobe reader - there should be something like security or similar where you can allow to use java script.  (I neither have AR X1 nor windows, so I cannot check how the option is called nowadays)

Comment: Thank you so much. It is indeed in Preferences, there was an option 3D & Multimedia -> "Enable 3D Content". Its working now :)

Comment: Note that you probably don't want this enabled by default: there's a reason it is disabled by default. Enable it only for documents you trust.

Comment: use `media9` package instead of `animate`

Comment: `media9` is *not* a good option here. Just enable JavaScript and `animate`-generated animations will run in AR. 3D and multimedia settings are not relevant here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in comments

Comment: @AlexG I enabled javascript in both Adobe and Foxit, and I still can't run an animated beamer presentation.